# Euro sign in PDF output from MS SQL Reporting Services

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, export

When I use FormatCurrency() in a report for Microsoft SQL Reporting Services I see a euro sign when I view the report through the report server's web interface in the default output format (or in Excel output) but when I export to PDF the euro sign becomes a small square.

How can I get euro signs in my reporting services PDFs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using OfficinaSans as a font. Using a more boring font like Arial solved the problem. Someone tipped me on good resource on the topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/donovans/pages/reporting-services-pdf-renderer-faq.aspx